# How to enable GRUB when using dual boot Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 dual booted with Windows 10. Everytime I switch my notebook on, I have to press F9, go to Boot manager, press Ubuntu and then GRUB menu is shown. I want GRUB to show when I start my notebook. Is there a way to do so ? If I don't press F9,Windows 10 is booted. I have disabled Fast Startup of Windows 10.

Comment: Are both Windows & Ubuntu in same boot mode, or both BIOS or both UEFI? Grub can only boot another system installed in same boot mode? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 2):

I have once had a similar problem with dual-booting with Microsoft Windows.

I solved the issue by taking the following steps.

1. Boot into Ubuntu.
2. Hold CTRL-ALT-T to open a terminal
3. Run:`sudo update-grub2` and allow GRUB to update it's list of operating systems.
4. Close Terminal.
5. Restart Computer.

Alternatively one could install and use boot repair [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

This should hopefully sort out the problem and show GRUB upon start up instead of Windows Boot Manager. Good luck.

Comment: It didn't work actually. Further more somehow ubuntu has lost its sound. During startup its does give the initial ubuntu sound, but after that nothing. I tried disabling Windows 10 Fast startup but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful solution from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7od9dPf4gnM&t=9s). I install Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 18.

1. If the BIOS selects Windows to run first by default, restart your PC then access Boot options in your BIOS to select Ubuntu to run first. (Press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> right after your PC boots, it depends on your PC manufacturer).
2. After Ubuntu is booted successfully, update the GRUB config file which is `/etc/default/grub`

   ```console
   sudo vim /etc/default/grub
   ```

   The file should look like this by default:

   ```bsh
   # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
   # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
   # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
   #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

   GRUB_DEFAULT=0
   GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   - Update the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` from `hidden` to `menu`
   - If the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is equal to 0, change it to any number but 0. The unit of this value is second.
3. Update the GRUB config file

   ```console
   sudo update-grub
   ```

---

The issue may be caused by:

- Install Ubuntu first when you use dual-boot.
- The GRUB menu is disabled for any reason.