# Dual-boot windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, windows, ssd

I have Ubuntu on SSD, use it as my main OS, but want to install win10 on separate SSD for gaming and to learn how to do it:) Need some help (good videos/articles/guides/solved question) to do it properly with GRUB and etc. I don`t want to reinstall Ubuntu and don`t have much experience in such things. Thanks in advance.

PC specs:

- CPU: I5-3470
- Motherboard: P8B75-M LX
- Both SSD`s are 2.5" SATA3

P.S.
First comment solution worked like a charm, more info how to set grub found here [How to enable GRUB when using dual boot Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676397/how-to-enable-grub-when-using-dual-boot-windows-10)

Comment: 1. Disconnect the Ubuntu SSD and install Windows. 2. Reconnect the Ubuntu SSD, and boot from it using UEFI settings. 3. For dual boot to work, run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi THX, it was waaaay easier than i expected

Comment: I have written it as an answer, which you can accept if that works for you.

Comment: Please accept the answer below that works for you. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disconnect the Ubuntu SSD and install Windows.
2. Reconnect the Ubuntu SSD, and boot from it using UEFI settings.
3. For dual boot to work, run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu.